# Using Java Jar Utility

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I found a jar utility that looks useful for some stuff I'm trying out. I downloaded the jar and put it in my eclipse lib and set the buildpath to include the jar. 
[image]


 And now I'm trying to use the demo that was included on the git hub, but I'm running into issues with using the utility's objects and the import cannot be resolved.
[image]

First time trying something like this, just hoping I'm overlooking something, this is the Git url. 
https://github.com/tbsalling/aismessages

Comment: It says it is available as a maven dependency, have you tried using that?

Comment: When you say, "set the buildpath to include the jar," you mean set the project's build path, correct?  That should be all that is required for Eclipse to recognize it.

Comment: Can you please give examples of what you're trying along with the error message?

Comment: I went to configure build path -> libraries ->add jars :/ I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade aismessages library from version 1.8 to 2.1, change to this version of library: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dk/tbsalling/aismessages/2.1.0/aismessages-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

you have aismessages 1.8 which is old, and have no AISInputStreamReader, you need aismessgas 2.1, and after library upgrade, everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to right-click the Project and select "properties".

And then go to "Build Path"

In Build Path, select "Add Jar" to select the Jar you need.

Comment: Also:  Verify that the Jar actually has the class.

Rename the file from "aismessages-1.08.jar"  to "aismessages-1.08.zip"


Unzip the Zip file, and explore the dirs and files that were in the zip file. See if your class really exists as a .class file.